# Storing bits in array of int

Tags: java, arrays, binary, bit

I need to create a method

```
private static int[] inBinary(int number)
```

that returns the binary representation of a number and stores it in an array, without any additional zeros.

Example : If I have the decimal number 2, it should return its binary value `10` and not `0010` or `00000010`.

The problem is that my code (for the dec number 2) returns 01 ( when I convert it into a void method and just print binary[i]) , instead of 10. My questions are, how can I "reverse" the function of the while-loop by the "result" variable, so that it returns 10 instead of 01 and how can I store all of it in an array. This is what I have so far :

```
public static int[] inBinary(int number){
    if(number < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative numbers not possible!");
    }
    int elements = 1; int result = 0; int[] binary = new int[elements]; 
    while(number != 0){
        elements++;
        result = number % 2;
             number /= 2;

             for(int i = 0; i < binary.length; i++){
                 binary[i] = result;

             }
    }
    return binary; 
  }
  public static void main (String[] args){
  System.out.println(inBinary(2));
  }
```

Comment: Look into bit shifting and bitwise `and` and `or`.

Comment: your `for` loop is overwriting the elements within the array at each iteration of the `while` loop, that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw , I just tried to reverse the order of the prints, so it starts from right to left. I  just wrote for(int i = binary.length - 1; i >= 0; i--), but it still isn't working.

Comment: The code as you provide it prints the following: `[I@7f690630`. Please provide a proper code sample.

Comment: I don't know where to start. Having `for` loop inside `while` loop makes no sense. You allocate the array with 1 element and never re-allocate it. You really need to understand what your code is supposed to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a home-made solution. It's a little less efficient, however, it works properly. Also, I can explain:

```
public static int[] inBinary(int number) {
    // this will store the full binary array
    int[] binary = new int[Integer.SIZE];
    for (int i = Integer.SIZE - 1; 0 <= i; i--) {
        binary[i] = number % 2;
        // one shift to the right, basically divides with two
        // it's okay to change the incoming parameter as it's not a reference
        number = number >> 1;
    }

    // then we count the leading zeros
    int startIndex = 0;
    while (binary[startIndex] != 1) {
        startIndex++;
    }

    // Arrays.copyOfRange() is prohibited so we have to do it manually:
    // We allocate a shorter array
    int[] result = new int[Integer.SIZE - startIndex];
    // and copy the related numbers.
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.SIZE - startIndex; i++) {
        result[i] = binary[startIndex + i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Now, what's wrong with this one? It works properly and doesn't use any code from the java lib. All it references is a constant: `Integer.SIZE`. You can replace it with `private static final int INTEGER_SIZE = 32;` if you like.

Comment: he just down-vote our answers, regardless how correct they are; he just dislike it.

Comment: @Kh.Taheri sounds like trolling.

Comment: However, I liked your answer, so here you are an up-vote from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] shiftbits(int[] array){

    int[] shiftedArray = new int[array.length];
    int index = array.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        shiftedArray[i] = array[index];
        index--;
    }

    return shiftedArray;

}
```

Comment: You don't find this useful ? Why you are using array ?

Comment: I'm using arrays, because that is my task. I must store all of the bits in the array. The problem is that I get them from left to right and I need them from right to left. Do you know an algorithm for reversing bits ?

Comment: We are trying to help you so you are not obliged to dislike each answer not corresponding to what you are looking for !!!

Comment: This method reverses an array. That's an important part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it for you; I used `util.List` in some parts because we dont know how long is the resulted binery number to define an array for it. The `reverse` methode used to reverse the binary array and remove the extra zeors; Here you are the entire code:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

       System.out.println(reverse(inBinary(2)));
    }

    public static Integer[] inBinary(int number) {
       if (number < 0) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative numbers not possible!");
       }
       int elements = 1;
       int result = 0;
       final List<Integer> binaryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       while (number != 0) {
          elements++;
          result = number % 2;
          number /= 2;
          binaryList.add(new Integer(result));
       }
       final Integer[] binary = new Integer[binaryList.size()];
       binaryList.toArray(binary);
       return binary;
   }

   static String reverse(final Integer arr[]) {
      boolean flag = false;
      String tmp = "";

      for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         if (arr[i].equals(new Integer(1)) && flag == false) {
             flag = true;
         }
         if (flag == true) {
             tmp += arr[i];
         }
      }
    return tmp;
  }
```

Comment: And one from me :)

Answer (score 0):

A very simplified working version of your program :

```
public static void inBinary(int number){
    if(number < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative numbers not possible!");
    }

   //create an empty list and fill binary digits in it
   List<Integer> binaryDigitsList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
   while(number != 0){
        int digit=number%2;
        binaryDigitsList.add(digit);
        number=number/2;
    }
    //now reverse the list and fill it in array
    int[] binaryArr = new int[binaryDigitsList.size()];
    for(int k=binaryDigitsList.size()-1, index=0; k>=0 ; k--){
        binaryArr[index]=binaryDigitsList.get(k);
        index++;
    }

    //print contents of array
    for(int index=0;index<binaryArr.length;index++)
        System.out.println("BinaryArray["+index+"] = "+binaryArr[index]); 
  }
```

Comment: if you dont want bit shifting then try this approach using arrays, just replace print statement of for loop with "return binaryArr" if you want to return  an int array from this method

Comment: @nasdenkov: did you try this approach? its short and simple

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming you want to use an array. here an example

```
public class ExempleDecimalBinary2 {


      public static void main(String a[]){
             ExempleDecimalBinary2 obj = new ExempleDecimalBinary2();

             System.out.println("\nBinary for 2: ");
             obj.inBinary(2);
             System.out.println("\nBinary for 124: ");
             obj.inBinary(124);
             System.out.println("\nBinary for 45: ");
             obj.inBinary(45);
             System.out.println("\nBinary for 2147483647: ");
             obj.inBinary(2147483647);



          }
    public static void inBinary(int number){
        int binary[] = new int[1];

         int index = 0;
         while(number > 0){

             binary=(int[]) resizeArray (binary, index+1);

           binary[index++] = number%2;

           number = number/2;
         }

         for(int i = index-1;i >= 0;i--){

           System.out.print(binary[i]);
         }

    }



    private static Object resizeArray (Object oldArray, int newSize) {
           int oldSize = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(oldArray);
           Class elementType = oldArray.getClass().getComponentType();
           Object newArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                 elementType, newSize);
           int preserveLength = Math.min(oldSize, newSize);
           if (preserveLength > 0)
              System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, preserveLength);
           return newArray; }
}
```